# Read a condition from a file java

Tags: java

**I'm not asking for codes I'm asking for logic so I can do it**

I wrote this java codes and I want the conditions to be read from a file.
How to do it?
I want to understand the logic.

I have tried putting each condition in a file and read form that.

```
    if(con == 1){
        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(new File("con.txt"));
    }
    else if(con == 2){
        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(new File("con2.txt"));
    }
    else if(con == 3){
        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(new File("con3.txt"));
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("You did not choose one of the 3 con");
    }
```

but it didn't work because in each if statement there is 2 conditions that need to be meet.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here.  See also: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: what are the 2 conditions ?

Answer (score 0):

So I can't really see conditions here, only a selection of 1,2 or 3. If that's the case, then you're better off using a switch, and then use your else as the default case.

---

So reading from a properties file just in case you need to load properties. Below is an example.

Firstly create a file called "**configuration.properties**" and for this example place the following;

- **property1=myPropertyOne**
- **property2=myPropertyTwo**
- **property3=myPropertyThree**

Now below is an example of reading the properties file, placing them into a [Java Properties Object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html), and then finally printing them to standard out.

```
Properties myProperties = new Properties();
InputStream fileInput = null; // Here so you can close it in the finally section 

try {
   fileInput = new FileInputStream("configuration.properties");
   myProperties.load(fileInput); // pass the input stream into properties to be read

   // print out all the properties values for given keys
   System.out.println(myProperties.getProperty("property1"));
   System.out.println(myProperties.getProperty("property2"));
   System.out.println(myProperties.getProperty("property3"));

} catch (IOException exceptionThrown) {
        // would be best to handle the exception here
} finally {
     if (fileInput != null) {
        try {
          fileInput.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          // handle exception for attempting to close handler
        }
     }
 }
```